# Overriding default datetime output format

Tags: postgresql

By default, my Postgres database outputs a DateTime in the current format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`. However, I want to override this and output it in this format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` with the `T` in between the date and the time.

Is there a way to override this with any format? I don't want to use `to_char` or anything similar, I want any DateTime returned by my database to be in that format (or any format I specify) by default.

Thanks

Comment: The database does not "output" anything; it stores the data. What does output your values is the client program that you use (which you failed to mention by the way), be it `psql` or something else. It would be a property of such program to define default formats for various data types.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! You could use [REGEXP_REPLACE]- but on the client side - but you apparently don't want that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do exactly what you wish, but here are 3 workaround ideas to consider:

---

#### views      *(“The good, ...”)*

Still need `To_Char()`, but at least not in every `SELECT`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (x TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL);

CREATE VIEW vt AS SELECT To_Char(x, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') AS x FROM t;

INSERT INTO t VALUES (Now());

SELECT t.x "table...", vt.x "...view" FROM t, vt;
```

```
      table...       |       ...view       
---------------------+---------------------
 2021-01-11 18:03:28 | 2021-01-11T18:03:28
```

Cleanest and least troublesome, therefore “good”.     `:-)`

---

#### `psql`'s `\o` transform      *(“...the bad, ...”)*

Only if you're using `psql`:

```sql
\o | sed -r 's/\<([12][0-9]{3}-[01][0-9]-[0123][0-9]) ([012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])\>/\1T\2/g'

SELECT x FROM t;
```

```
          x          
---------------------
 2021-01-11T18:03:28
```

Risky and utterly nonportable, therefore “bad”.     `:-)`

---

#### custom datatype      *(“...and the ugly.”)*

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xtypes.html ; two key sentences,

> Creating a new base type requires implementing functions to operate on the type in a low-level language, usually C.

> A user-defined type must always have input and output functions.

Many maintenance and deployment headaches, therefore “ugly”.     `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that in PostgreSQL.

The only configuration parameter available is `DateStyle`, which allows you to choose between a handful of pre-defined output formats.